# Pandas - plotting user RFM

Tags: python, pandas, plot, plotly, seaborn

Given the following DF of user RFM activity:

```
   uid   R  F   M
0    1  10  1   5
1    1   2  2  10
2    1   4  3   1
3    1   5  4  10
4    2  10  1   3
5    2   1  2  10
6    2   1  3   4
```

> Recency: The time between the last purchase and today, represented by
> the distance between the rightmost circle and the vertical dotted line
> that's labeled Now.
>
> Frequency: The time between purchases, represented by the distance
> between the circles on a single line.
>
> Monetary: The amount of money spent on each purchase, represented by
> the size of the circle. This amount could be the average order value
> or the quantity of products that the customer ordered.

I would like to plot something like the figure below:
[image]

Where the size of the circle is the `M` value and the distance is the `R`. Any help would be appreciated.

**Update**
As suggested by Diziet Asahi I've tried the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_users(df):
  fig, ax = plt.subplots()
  ax.axis('off')
  ax.scatter(x=df['M'],y=df['uid'],s=30*df['R'], marker='o', color='grey')
  ax.invert_xaxis()
  ax.axvline(0, ls='--', color='black', zorder=-1)
  for y in df['uid'].unique():
      ax.axhline(y, color='grey', zorder=-1)

tmp = pd.DataFrame({'uid':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2],'R':[10,2,4,5,10,1,1],'F':[1,2,3,4,1,3,4],'M':[5,10,1,10,3,10,4]})
plot_users(tmp)
```

And I get the following:
[image]

So I think there is a bug, since first user has 4 records and the sizes also doesn't match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use matplotlib's `scatter()` with the `s=` argument to draw markers with an area proportional to the value in `M`. The rest is just tweaking the appearance of the plot.

```py
c = 'xkcd:dark grey'
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axis('off')
ax.scatter(x=df['R'],y=df['uid'],s=60*df['M'], marker='o', color=c)
ax.invert_xaxis()
ax.axvline(0, ls='--', color=c, zorder=-1)
for y in df['uid'].unique():
    ax.axhline(y, color=c, zorder=-1)
ax.set_ymargin(1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, please see my comments

Comment: Sorry, I got mixed up between `R` and `M`. This should be ok now. Note that uid=2 has only 2 points because two of the rows have the same 'R' value. I don't know what you want to do with those.

Comment: Thanks again, note that R value is recency from **last** event, therefore same value can occur. other than that, a beautiful solution.

Comment: Your explanations say that R is the time between purchase and today, not between purchases. Do you mean to say that uid 1 should have dots at coordinates 10,12,16 and 21?

Comment: You are  right, my bad ... my last question: when I plot a lot of data, it seems that the rows overlap, how can I spread  the users  row evenly across the height of  the chart?

Comment: if you have sequential `uid`, then they should be evenly spaced already and you just need to increase the vertical size of the figure (see [`figsize`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html?highlight=figure%20size)). If your `uid` are not sequential, then you should create a new column with sequential numbers to use as y-values